# 404 redirect not functioning in Express Application

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

i have this routes.coffee

```
#### Routes
# We are setting up theese routes:
#
# GET, POST, PUT, DELETE methods are going to the same controller methods - we dont care.
# We are using method names to determine controller actions for clearness.
urls = [
  "map"
  "guide"
]

module.exports = (app) ->
  #   - _/_ -> controllers/index/index method
  app.all "/", (req, res, next) ->
    routeMvc("index", "index", req, res, next)

  for url in urls
    do (url) ->
      app.all "/#{url}", (req, res, next) ->
        res.render "#{url}"
        routeMvc("#{url}", "#{url}", req, res, next)

  #   - _/**:controller**_  -> controllers/***:controller***/index method
  app.all "/:controller", (req, res, next) ->
    routeMvc(req.params.controller, "index", req, res, next)

  #   - _/**:controller**/**:method**_ -> controllers/***:controller***/***:method*** method
  app.all "/:controller/:method", (req, res, next) ->
    routeMvc(req.params.controller, req.params.method, req, res, next)

  #   - _/**:controller**/**:method**/**:id**_ -> controllers/***:controller***/***:method*** method with ***:id*** param passed
  app.all "/:controller/:method/:id", (req, res, next) ->
    routeMvc(req.params.controller, req.params.method, req, res, next)

  # If all else failed, show 404 page
  app.all "*", (req, res, next) ->
    console.warn "error 404: ", req.url
    res.statusCode = 404
    res.render "404", 404

# render the page based on controller name, method and id
routeMvc = (controllerName, methodName, req, res, next) ->
  controllerName = "index" if not controllerName?
  controller = null
  try
    controller = require "./controllers/" + controllerName
  catch e
    console.warn "controller not found: " + controllerName, e
    next()
    return
  data = null
  if typeof controller[methodName] is "function"
    actionMethod = controller[methodName].bind controller
    actionMethod req, res, next
  else
    console.warn "method not found: " + methodName
    next()
```

and in my index.coffee is like:

```
...

app.use blade.middleware(process.cwd() + "/views")
# Initialize routes
routes = require "./routes"
routes(app)
app.use app.router

#### Finalization
# Register i18next AppHelper so we can use the translate function in template
i18n.registerAppHelper(app)
app.locals.pretty=true

# Export application object
module.exports = app
```

this does not work as expected in that none of the 404 routes are being serviced!

routeMVC is run as i get an console.log warning:

```
controller not found: calendar { [Error: Cannot find module './controllers/calendar'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
error 404:  /calendar
```

what am i missing?

Comment: Is `routeMvc` being run? If so, what do the `console.warn` messages say? What *do* you get as response when you try a URL that should trigger a 404?

Comment: The last line (`error 404: /calendar`) suggests that the 404 route is run just fine. If you're not getting the proper response, check to make sure that `res.render()` can find its template (and that it can be rendered without errors; the second `404` argument looks strange, since you don't generally pass scalars to template engines).

Comment: thanks that was it, i changed `res.statusCode = 404
res.render "404", 404` to 
`res.render '404', status: 404` and it is ok now.